# Cannot enable host mic when connected via RDP

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop, microphone

I am using a mac OS X 10.9.3 and I am remoting into a windows 8.1 machine using Microsoft Remote Desktop.

I need a microphone enabled on the windows 8.1 machine for some software to work properly. I do not care to be able to use the microphone or redirect it from my mac (mac rdp does not support it), I just need one there.

When I am logged in directly, the software sees the microphone and works fine. When I am remoted in, there is no microphone available and the software does not work properly. I look under "recording devices" in the sound setup and it says "No audio devices are installed".

Comment: RDP to a Win 7 machine here shows Sound Device as "Remote Audio" for input & output. I can hear it 'ding' but I've never tried sending it any signal, so can't comment on whether that would be sufficient for your usage. Is RDP up to date? Mine is 8.0.9. Edit/Session is set to "Play on Device"

Comment: If I set to "Play on Remote PC" I get the same options as if I went to the machine itself, HD Pro Webcam mic.

Comment: Humm, I do not see "remote audio" under recording devices. I am running 8.0.9 as well. I do need to hear audio so I cannot just turn it off all together. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Differences left are that I'm on 10.9.5 & Win 7.1; & that my 'remote' is in the same building, same network. Other than that, I'm not sure.